# IEDriverServer.exe does not exist in C# Selenium Web driver

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Developed a WPF application in C# using selenium web driver. Given the IEdrive path as follows and it works fine.

```
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"E:\AG\myGateway\myGateway_FF\driver");
```

But when I given the path like below

```
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"http:\10.200.0.86\drivers");
```

then the following error throws out.

```
The file http:\10.200.0.86\drivers\IEDriverServer.exe does not exist.
```

Because I need to publish the WPF in my localhost. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, I have followed the below steps.

1.Created a new directory in the client system.

```
private static string _localpath = @"D:\Gateway\Drivers\";
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(_localpath);
```

2.Then separately downloaded the driver and stored in the local path under directory which was created in the first step.

```
private static string _IEdriverpath = "http://10.200.0.86/Drivers/IEDriverServer.exe";
private static string _localpathIE = @"D:\Gateway\Drivers\IEDriverServer.exe";
wc.DownloadFile(_IEdriverpath, _localpathIE);
```

3.Finally executed the selenium command

```
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(_localpath);
```